# A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to create a user sign up profile.Here is the code. But i run my server. try to open my admin panel it shows (A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.). Help me out
This is my model

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
        First Name and Last Name do not cover name patterns around the globe.
    """
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=20,
                                unique=True)
    adress = models.CharField(_("Address"), max_length=20,
                                     blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=15, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(_("Country"), max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
     #   return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'username': self.username})

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

And my setting.py is

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6b3k$&lk-mt08%di2#%oj+ggr=7r_)_7#=uomzsj)jk&yy@tg^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'login',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

import django.contrib.auth
django.contrib.auth.LOGIN_URL = '/'

INTERNAL_IPS = '127.0.0.1'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.User'
```

Comment: Where does it show that? Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Also please post your model structure in **models.py** file. Is Sub_category a model in your project.?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to get a category from a given id.

```
def test_carete_sub_category(self):
    category_id = 1
    category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
    ...
```

When testing, you have to create some objects in order to check the code works. In this example `Category` object. If not, this will raise an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception

There are several ways to create these objects in your tests. Here is 2 possible ways:

1) You can dump some models of your database in a json file.

Run `python manage.py dumpdata myapp.category 1> categories.json`, copy it to the `fixtures` sub-directory of your app
and load it as a fixture in your tests

```
class ProjectTests(APITestCase):
    # This create the objects from dump for each test
    fixtures = ['categories.json']  

    def test_carete_sub_category(self):
         # Get the category object with id 1 defined in categories.json
         category = Category.objects.get(id=1)  
         ...
```

2) You can create the objects in the `setUp` method of your TestCase

```
class ProjectTests(APITestCase):
    # This is called before each test
    def setUp(self):
         the_args_for_creation = {'name': 'bal-bla'}
         self._cat_id = Category.objects.create(** the_args_for_creation).id   

    def test_carete_sub_category(self):
         # Get the category object
         category = Category.objects.get(id=self._cat_id)  
         ...
```

You may be interested by [django-model-mommy](http://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html) or [django-factory-boy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html) to make object creation easier in your tests.

Of course, the object creation can be done in the test itself rather than in the `setUp`. If done in `setUp`, the objects will be created at the beginning of each test.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. setUp() works. But when I am using that category in my test_case it showing <Category: Branch> is not JSON serializable

Comment: I guess that this is a different problem. You should ask another question.